# How to do Doctrine2 calculated fields ordering

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've got the following doctrine2 query working nicely, it retrieves all 'markers' within some geographical radius.

```
    $qb->select('marker')
        ->from('SndSpecialistLocator\Entity\Marker', 'marker')
        ->where('DISTANCE(marker.location, POINT_STR(:point)) < :distance')
        ->setParameter('point', $point)
        ->setParameter('distance', $radius);
```

Now I want to sort them by distance.

```
    $qb->select('marker (DISTANCE(marker.location, POINT_STR(:point))) AS distance')
        ->from('SndSpecialistLocator\Entity\Marker', 'marker')
        ->where('DISTANCE(marker.location, POINT_STR(:point)) < :distance')
        ->setParameter('point', $point)
        ->orderBy('distance', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('distance', $radius);
```

But unfortunately this does not work, I am wondering is this possible as distance is not a real property of my entity, but a calculated one?

What is the trick here?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, try using HIDDEN in your call to select() :

```
$qb->select('m as marker, (DISTANCE(m.location, POINT_STR(:point))) as HIDDEN distance')
// note HIDDEN added here --->------->------->------->------->------->---^
    ->from('SndSpecialistLocator\Entity\Marker', 'm')
    ->where('DISTANCE(m.location, POINT_STR(:point)) < :distance')
    ->setParameter('point', $point)
    ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
    ->setParameter('distance', $radius)
    ->setMaxResults(5);

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->execute();
```

Adding HIDDEN to the SELECT clause hides it from the results but allows it to be used in the orderby clause. Your $result should then contain the objects you want without having to do the extra array_walk.

Comment: Excellent answer, this was exactly what I was looking for. Take my upvote

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ordering by aliases is not possible. 
What you can do* instead is to manually repeat the function in your orderBy statement:

```
$qb->select('marker (DISTANCE(marker.location, POINT_STR(:point))) AS distance')
    ->from('SndSpecialistLocator\Entity\Marker', 'marker')
    ->where('DISTANCE(marker.location, POINT_STR(:point)) < :distance')
    ->setParameter('point', $point)
    ->orderBy('DISTANCE(marker.location, POINT_STR(:point))', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter('distance', $radius);
```

**We will probably all end up in dev-hell for stepping off the holy path of DRY*

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
   $qb->select('m as marker, (DISTANCE(m.location, POINT_STR(:point))) as distance')
        ->from('SndSpecialistLocator\Entity\Marker', 'm')
        ->where('DISTANCE(m.location, POINT_STR(:point)) < :distance')
        ->setParameter('point', $point)
        ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')
        ->setParameter('distance', $radius)
        ->setMaxResults(5);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $result = $query->execute();

    /**
     * Convert the resulting associative array into one containing only the entity objects
     *
     * array (size=5)
     *   0 =>
     *     array (size=2)
     *       'marker' =>
     *         object(SndSpecialistLocator\Entity\Marker)[647]
     *           protected 'id' => int 43
     *           protected 'title' => string 'c5d07acdd47efbe38a6d0bf4ec64f333' (length=32)
     *           private 'location' =>
     *             object(SndSpecialistLocator\Orm\Point)[636]
     *                private 'lat' => float 52.2897
     *                private 'lng' => float 4.84268
     *       'distance' => string '0.0760756823433058' (length=18)
     *   1 => ...
     *
     * array (size=5)
     *   0 =>
     *     object(SndSpecialistLocator\Entity\Marker)[647]
     *       protected 'id' => int 43
     *       protected 'title' => string 'c5d07acdd47efbe38a6d0bf4ec64f333' (length=32)
     *       private 'location' =>
     *         object(SndSpecialistLocator\Orm\Point)[636]
     *           private 'lat' => float 52.2897
     *           private 'lng' => float 4.84268
     *   1 => ...
     *
     */
    array_walk($result, function (&$item, $key)
    {
        $item = $item['marker'];
    });
```